# Geometric Brownian motion simulated with three different methods gives three different results

Tags: stochastic-calculus

My code:

```
Import["http://halirutan.github.io/Mathematica-SE-Tools/decode.m"] 
   ["https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytfey.png"]

Remove["Global`*"]

k = 
  RandomFunction[
    GeometricBrownianMotionProcess[-0.00096, 0.239317, 3061. 44], 
    {0, 5, 1}];
s = k["Values"]; 
s[[5]]

Remove["Global`*"]

s[0] = 3061.44;
r = -0.000960;
σ = 0.239317;
Δt = 1;
s[u_] := s[u - 1]*Exp[(r - 0.5*σ^2)*Δt + Sqrt[Δt]*σ*z[[u + 1]]];
w = RandomFunction[WienerProcess[r, σ], {0, 5, 1}];
z = w["Values"];
s[5]

Remove["Global`*"]

s[0] = 3061.44;
r= -0.00096;
σ = 0.239317;
Δt = 1;
s[x_] := 
  s[x - 1] * 
    Exp[(r - 0.5*σ^2)*Δt + 
           Sqrt[Δt]*σ*InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], RandomReal[]]];
s[5]
```

Why is there a difference between these three methods? I know that each specific number has to be different, because each formula uses a determinisitc and a stochastic part, which makes it impossible to get the exact same number with all the methods. What I've noticed is, that the stochastic part of each of those methods behaves differently, so much so, that when used in a monte carlo context, all three formulae lead to remarkably distinct results (deviations between 1 and 10).
These are the values for the different variables:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

First comes the GeometricBrownianMotionProcess formula:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then there's the same formula with the WienerProcess:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And then there's the formula usually found in books:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In the end, all three of those functions should return geometric brownian results, no? Yet, this somehow isn't the case. I need to generate 5 different stock prices s[1] up to s[5], and, once I apply these formulae in a Monte Carlo Simulation, all three lead to distinct results, even after a million simulations. What are the differences? Am I using correct parameters for each process?

Edit: Here is the Mathematica notebook with all the necessary code (copy everything below (including Import) into an open notebook and press enter):

Import["http://halirutan.github.io/Mathematica-SE-Tools/decode.m"]["https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytfey.png"]

Comment: Please post code as text, rather than as images, so people can copy / paste it and run it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP's code has been given in images making it too difficult for those who might otherwise help to work with the code.

Comment: I added the Mathematica code just now...

Comment: I still can't see the code...

Comment: Copy and paste this into an open notebook and press enter: Import["http://halirutan.github.io/Mathematica-SE-Tools/decode.m"]["http://i.stack.imgur.com/ytfey.png"]

Comment: @Lumberjack88 people don’t like to import  invisible code from unknown sources. You should simply copy and paste your code in to your original question and format it appropriately (select then ctrl+k).

Comment: I added a separate source code box now.

Comment: In the second form I don't understand how you link `s` and `w`; in the third approach I think you can just use `RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1]]` and replace the `InverseCDF`.

Comment: In the second approach, w is a time series with corresponding wiener process results. z then only picks out the wiener process values and leaves the time information out. The z value is the used in then stochastic part of the exp function.

Comment: @m_goldberg: Why is this question on hold? I have provided the additional code in three various forms. What else do I need to provide so as to make it compatible with the rules?

Comment: It's on hold for reasons that applied before you added the code in markdown format. Now, that the question has been edited, it will come up for a reopen vote. I have already voted to reopen. Five reopen votes are needed to reinstate the question.